# Reflection from a spherical surface

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics

I am self-studying Optics by Pedrotti and I'm stuck on the algebra for an example of spherical reflection.

We have a point source at O that reflects off a spherical surface and creates a virtual image at I.

[image]

Assume that $\alpha$ and $\phi$ are small so that the small angle approximation holds. Then

$$
\theta = \alpha + \phi
$$
$$
2\theta = \alpha + \alpha'
$$
so
$$
\alpha - \alpha' = -2\phi
$$
Applying the small angle approximation,
$$
\frac{h}{s}-\frac{h}{s'}=-2\frac{h}{R}
$$

The thing I'm stuck on is pretty simple. If I apply the small angle approximation to $\alpha'$, for example, I get
$$
\alpha'\approx \tan\alpha' = h/x
$$

where $x$ is the length of the adjacent side of the triangle. But how can I argue that $x\approx s'$. I can "see" it from the limit as the angles become small, but how do I argue this mathematically?

---

EDIT

Reading further a bit, Pedrotti writes (without much elaboration)

> ... where we have also neglected the axial distance $VQ$...

But that's not very satisfying! So I'm still wondering what the mathematical argument is that $x\approx s'$.

Comment: $s' - x = VC - QC = R(1-\cos\varphi)$ which has a 2nd order Taylor expansion of $s'-x = R\frac12\varphi^2$. If $\varphi$ is small as you say then this can be neglected.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I probably should've made it an answer in the first place but anyways I wrote it up with a bit more detail as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between $s' = VI$ and $x = QI$, $s' - x = VQ$, is equivalent to the length $VC - QC = R - R\cos\varphi$. Substituting the Taylor expansion $\cos\varphi \approx 1 - \frac12\varphi^2$ shows that the difference is 2nd order in $\varphi$:
$$s' - x \approx \frac12 R\varphi^2$$
Which can be neglected for small $\varphi$, meaning $s' \approx x$.